# Download all pubmed central article ids that have a keyword appearing in their titles/abstracts and also falling between two dates

Tags: python, biopython

I am using the following code to download all pubmed central article ids that have a keyword appearing in their titles/abstracts and also falling between two dates. The code seems to work when I select database = "pubmed" but when I switch to database = "pmc" I get empty list. For example, using the start and end dates as mentioned in the code I get 4 PubMed ids: ['36902449', '36880658', '36583446', '35239250'] and when I check manually, the first one among them (which is '36902449') is also present in PMC database, of course, the id is different (10003631) but same article. The code is expected to fetch that id. I'd appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm missing here.

```
import os
import datetime
from Bio import Entrez

# Set the email address to identify yourself to NCBI
Entrez.email = "example@gmail.com"

# Set the date range for the search
start_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 22)

# Format the dates as strings in the correct format
start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

# Build the search query with the date range
keyword = "dosage compensation"
# database = "pubmed"
database = "pmc"

# Use esearch to fetch the list of matching article IDs
if database == "pubmed":
    search_term = f'("{start_date_str}"[Date - Publication] : "{end_date_str}"[Date - Publication]) AND {keyword}[Title/Abstract]'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db=database,
                            term=search_term,
                            retmax=100,
                            api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'])
elif database == "pmc":
    search_term = f'("{start_date_str}"[Publication Date] : "{end_date_str}"[Publication Date]) AND {keyword}[Title/Abstract] AND open_access[filter]'
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db=database,
                        term=search_term,
                        retmax=1000,
                        api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'])

record = Entrez.read(handle)
id_list = record['IdList']
handle.close()

# Print the number of matching articles
print(f"Found {len(id_list)} articles published between {start_date_str} and {end_date_str} in {database}")
# print(id_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message "PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY is not set. Please set the environment variable PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY with your PMC API key" indicates that the environment variable PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY is not defined. To resolve this issue, you need to set the PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY environment variable with your PMC API key.
Here's how you can set the environment variable PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY:
Open a terminal or command prompt.
Set the environment variable using the following command (replace YOUR_PMC_API_KEY with your actual PMC API key):
For Windows:

```
setx PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY "YOUR_PMC_API_KEY"
```

After setting the environment variable, you can verify it by printing its value in your terminal or command prompt:

```
echo %PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY%
```

For macOS or Linux:

```
export PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY="YOUR_PMC_API_KEY"
#verify
echo $PMC_ENTREZ_API_KEY
```

also if u have no API_KEY, then you have to obtain your PMC API key,

1. Create an account on the PubMed Central (PMC) website.
2. Sign In, navigate to your account settings or developer settings.
3. Click on option to generate or obtain an API key. and follow the instructions, in Cas eu find difficulty, go through the documentation provided by PubMed Central or contact them for support for assistance.